# Как задать собственный id для sql базы данных (c#,code-first, visualstudio2017, entityframework)?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, codefirst

Мне нужно, чтобы в моей таблице Groups ключевое поле задавалось мной в программе, как показано ниже в main. Вместо этого при просмотре через SQL Manager в таблице поле post_id задается как (1,2,3,4,5 ...), а не как я ставил допустим 228.

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int post_id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}


class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("DbConnectionString") {

    }


    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   using (var context = new MyDbContext())
   {
        var t = new Group()
        {
            post_id = 228,
            text = "test1"
        };
        context.Groups.Add(t);
        context.SaveChanges();
   }
 }


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnectionString" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog = Music3;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Comment: Спасибо, сработало